# How can I make my Perl method more Moose-like?

Tags: perl, moose

I am practising [Kata Nine: Back to the CheckOut](http://codekata.pragprog.com/2007/01/kata_nine_back_.html) in Perl whilst also trying to use Moose for the first time.

So far, I've created the following class:

```
package Checkout;

# $Id$
#

use strict;
use warnings;

our $VERSION = '0.01';

use Moose;
use Readonly;

Readonly::Scalar our $PRICE_OF_A => 50;

sub price {
    my ( $self, $items ) = @_;

    if ( defined $items ) {
        $self->{price} = 0;

        if ( $items eq 'A' ) {
            $self->{price} = $PRICE_OF_A;
        }
    }

    return $self->{price};
}

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

no Moose;

1;
```

The whole `price` method doesn't feel very Moose-ish and I feel like this could be refactored further.

Does anyone have any input on how this could be improved?

Comment: Whenever I refactor a species (Moose) I always start by extracting the subfamily. In this case Capreolinea http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capreolinae

Comment: Looks like you're returning a price of 0 if items is specified? is this correct?

Comment: Ether look again. 0 if defined *and* not eq 'A'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First thing I noticed is that you're not using an explicit attribute for your
class.

```
$self->{price} = 0;
```

This violates most of the encapsulation that using Moose provides. A Moose solution
would at the *least* make `price` into an actual attribute.

```
use 5.10.0; # for given/when

has '_price' => ( is => 'rw' );

sub price {
    my ( $self, $item ) = @_;
    given ($item) {
        when ('A') { $self->_price($PRICE_OF_A) }
        default    { $self->_price(0) }
    }
}
```

However the main problem with the code you've presented is that you're not
really modeling the problem described by the Kata. First the Kata specifically
states that you'll need to pass in the pricing rules on each invocation of the
Checkout Object. So we know we'll need to save this state in something other
than a series of ReadOnly class variables.

```
has pricing_rules => (
    isa     => 'HashRef',
    is      => 'ro',
    traits  => ['Hash'],
    default => sub { {} },
    handles => {
        price     => 'get',
        has_price => 'exists'
    },
);
```

You'll see the price method here is now a delegate using Moose's "Native
Attributes" delegation. This will perform a lookup between an Item and a Rule.
This however won't handle the case of a lookup on a element that doesn't
exist. Peeking ahead one of the unit tests the Kata provides is exactly that
kind of a lookup:

```
is( price(""),     0 ); # translated to Test::More
```

So we'll need to modify the price method slightly to handle that case.
Basically we check to see if we have a price rule, otherwise we return 0.

```
around 'price' => sub {
    my ( $next, $self, $item ) = @_;
    return 0 unless $self->has_price($item);
    $self->$next($item);
};
```

Next we'll need to track the items as they're scanned so we can build a total.

```
has items => (
    isa     => 'ArrayRef',
    traits  => ['Array'],
    default => sub { [] },
    handles => {
        scan  => 'push',
        items => 'elements'
    },
);
```

Again the "Native Attributes" delegation provides the `scan` method that the
test in the Kata are looking for.

```
# Translated to Test::More
my $co = Checkout->new( pricing_rules => $RULES );
is( $co->total, 0 );
$co->scan("A");
is( $co->total, 50 );
```

Finally a `total` method is trivial using `List::Util`'s `sum` function.

```
sub total {
    my ($self) = @_;
    my @prices = map { $self->price($_) } $self->items;
    return sum( 0, @prices );
}
```

This code doesn't fully implement the solution to the Kata, but it does
present a much better model of the problem state and show's a much more
"Moosey" solution.

The full code and translated tests are presented below.

```
{

    package Checkout;
    use Moose;
    our $VERSION = '0.01';
    use namespace::autoclean;

    use List::Util qw(sum);

    has pricing_rules => (
        isa     => 'HashRef',
        is      => 'ro',
        traits  => ['Hash'],
        default => sub { {} },
        handles => {
            price     => 'get',
            has_price => 'exists'
        },
    );

    around 'price' => sub {
        my ( $next, $self, $item ) = @_;
        return 0 unless $self->has_price($item);
        $self->$next($item);
    };

    has items => (
        isa     => 'ArrayRef',
        traits  => ['Array'],
        default => sub { [] },
        handles => {
            scan  => 'push',
            items => 'elements'
        },
    );

    sub total {
        my ($self) = @_;
        my @prices = map { $self->price($_) } $self->items;
        return sum( 0, @prices );
    }

    __PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
}

{

    package main;
    use 5.10.0;
    use Test::More;

    our $RULES = { A => 50 };    # need a full ruleset

    sub price {
        my ($goods) = @_;
        my $co = Checkout->new( pricing_rules => $RULES ); # use BUILDARGS the example API 
        for ( split //, $goods ) { $co->scan($_) }
        return $co->total;
    }

  TODO: {
        local $TODO = 'Kata 9 not implemented';

        is( price(""),     0 );
        is( price("A"),    50 );
        is( price("AB"),   80 );
        is( price("CDBA"), 115 );

        is( price("AA"),     100 );
        is( price("AAA"),    130 );
        is( price("AAAA"),   180 );
        is( price("AAAAA"),  230 );
        is( price("AAAAAA"), 260 );

        is( price("AAAB"),   160 );
        is( price("AAABB"),  175 );
        is( price("AAABBD"), 190 );
        is( price("DABABA"), 190 );

        my $co = Checkout->new( pricing_rules => $RULES );
        is( $co->total, 0 );
        $co->scan("A");
        is( $co->total, 50 );
        $co->scan("B");
        is( $co->total, 80 );
        $co->scan("A");
        is( $co->total, 130 );
        $co->scan("A");
        is( $co->total, 160 );
        $co->scan("B");
        is( $co->total, 175 );
    }

    done_testing();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `use strict;` and `use warnings;` can be removed as `use Moose;` will already do that for you. You can also use Moose to create read-only attribute instead of using `Readonly` module.

```
package Checkout;

# $Id$                                                                                                                                                                        
#                                                                                                                                                                             

our $VERSION = '0.01';

use Moose;

has '_prices' => (
  is => 'ro',
  isa => 'HashRef',
  lazy_build => 1,
  init_arg => undef, # do not allow in constructor                                                                                                                            
);

sub _build__prices {
    my ( $self ) = @_;

    return {
            'A' => 50
           };
}

sub price {
    my ( $self, $items ) = @_;

    return (exists $self->_prices->{$items} ? $self->_prices->{$items} : 0);
}

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

no Moose;

1;
```

Comment: The per-object read-only attribute is conceptually not the same as the read-only class variable in in the OP's code!

Comment: The read-only class variable however is incorrect when you read the original Kata